# Proof that any two initial algebras are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, category-theory

I am trying to prove: If $A_1$ and $A_2$ are initial algebras in a class $K$, then $A_1$ is isomorphic to $A_2$.

My teacher's proof is:

> Let $f$ be a unique morphism from $A_1$ to $A_2$
>
> Let $g$ be a unique morphism from $A_2$ to $A_1$
>
> $f;g: A_1\to A_1$
>
> $1_{A_1}:A_1\to A_1$
>
> $A_1$ is initial
>
> So, $f;g = 1_{A_1}$
>
> Similarly for $g;f = 1_{A_2}$
>
> So, $A_1$ is imorphic to $A_2$

I don't understand why $f;g = 1_{A_1}$. Yes, there can be only one morphism from $A_2$ to $A_1$ (in this case, $g$) because $A_1$ is initial, but why does $g$ have to 'transform' the value from $A_2$ to exactly the value it received from $A_1$ (so, $1_{A_1}$)? Can't it 'transform' the value to something else? It is just a morphism.

Comment: Mathjax/LaTeX, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the definition of a category, $Hom(A_1,A_1)$ must contain the identity morphism on $A_1$. By the definition of initial object, there is only one morphism from $A_1\to A_1$, so that's all there is.

Now $fg$ is a morphism from $A_1\to A_1$, and guess what: there's only one thing it could be!

Comment: For example, f(1) = 2, but g(2) = 3. Why must g(f(1)) be 1? In this case, it would be 3. What am I missing?

Comment: But, wouldn't that mean that any two morphisms: f: A → B and g: B → A, will be an isomorphism?

Comment: @TomaRadu-Petrescu Do you agree there is only one thing in $Hom(A_1,A_1)$, and that by definition of categories, it must be the identity morphism?  After you agree to that, you must also agree that $fg$ is in this one element set.

Comment: I would have agreed if I knew what Hom or a category is.

Comment: I think I understand. So, when we are talking about an initial algebra inside a class, there will be morphisms from it to all the other algebras from that class, but ALSO to itself and in this case, the only option is the identity function. And that's why f;g is forced to be the identity.

Comment: @TomaRadu-Petrescu I'm pretty sure I had the same confusion you had when I was first proving the uniqueness of the tensor product :)